# ios Facebook Log Out completely log out safari keeps data

Tags: facebook, session, logging, sdk, out

In the iOS Facebook SDK, when I use

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

this only closes the token. Then when I open Safari, I can still reach the Facebook account in Safari.

How can I eliminate this behavior?

In my app, many users are using the same iPhone. So they need to authenticate as usual. When the user selects "close session" in the app and opens www.facebook.com, it appears logged in with the user's credentials.

When the user clicks "end session", the application must log out from Facebook as well.